# UIAlertView crash private method on iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, crash, uialertview

The stack is as below, how to fix this crash ?
It is only in iOS7 and why there is uitableview in the stack?

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 5
1 UIKit -[UIAlertView(Private) modalItem:shouldDismissForButtonAtIndex:] + 62
2 UIKit -[_UIModalItemsCoordinator _notifyDelegateModalItem:tappedButtonAtIndex:] + 94
3 UIKit -[_UIModalItemAlertContentView tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 894
4 UIKit -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1078
5 UIKit -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 214
6 UIKit _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 316
7 UIKit _afterCACommitHandler + 430
8 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
```

---

```
- (id)initWithIdentifier:(LTAlertMsgIdentifier)alertIdentifier
                delegate:(id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/)delegate
       cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
       otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... {

    LTAlertMsgManager *sharedAlertMsgMgr = [LTAlertMsgManager shareAlertManageInstance];

    NSString *strMsg = [sharedAlertMsgMgr getLTAlertMsgByAlertID:alertIdentifier];
    if ([NSString isBlankString:strMsg]){
        // alert is invalid, if alert message is empty
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *strTitle = [sharedAlertMsgMgr getLTAlertTitleByAlertID:alertIdentifier];
    if (self = [super initWithTitle:([NSString isBlankString:strTitle] ? nil : strTitle)
                            message:strMsg
                           delegate:delegate
                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                  otherButtonTitles:nil]){
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, otherButtonTitles);
        for (NSString *arg = otherButtonTitles; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*))
        {
            [self addButtonWithTitle:arg];
        }
        va_end(args);
    }

    NSLog(@"cancel button index - %d", self.cancelButtonIndex);
    return self;

}
```

Comment: please show us didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Describe the alert view. What are you doing at the time it crashes.

Comment: UIAlertView is not meant for subclassing.

Comment: Form the reference *The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.*

Comment: @vikingosegundo True, but if you don't change the view hierarchy, subclassing works in general. The error is not caused by subclassing.

Comment: How do you `show` the alert?

Answer (score 2):

The buttons in the `UIAlertView` are implemented using a `UITableView`. That's why tapping a button triggers a `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Typical problems causing such errors are:

1. Alert not displayed from the main thread
2. Delegate already deallocated (make sure the alert delegate is retained somewhere for the entire life of the alert).

Comment: All the stack is as below, and i can not reproduce this issue. So, i can not trace and fix this. Only review the alert related code? Thanks!

Comment: @user3327566 The code you have added is okey. The more important is how the alert is shown and its delegate.

Answer (score 0):

See [iOS 7 bug or my bug in UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001528/ios-7-bug-or-my-bug-in-uialertview)

UIAlertView delegate is
`@property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate`, so ensure `alertView.delegate = nil` when delegate is dealloced.