# How to refresh the uitableivew with an alertview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

In the .m file:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RememberedTableListCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"word"];
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)resetList:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    UIAlertView *resetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reset" message:@"Are you sure to reset the list?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [resetAlert show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    // the user clicked Yes
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // reset the list

        //reload table data
        NSLog(@"button yes is clicked");

        for (NSMutableDictionary*l in listAll) {
             [l setValue:@"0" forKey:@"remembered"];
        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        //[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{[self.tvRemembered reloadData];}];

        //[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


        NSLog(@"refreshing...");


    }

}
```

How to refresh the **UITableView** with an **UIAlertView Delegate**? I have tried `reloadData:` and `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` like the above. But they didn't help. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you log any statement for buttonIndex one?

Comment: yes I did, it's fine.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for `alertView`?

Comment: Put break point It may be happen your AlertView delegate is not Called.

Comment: do not forget to assign alert view delegate to nil. It seems to be ios 7 bug. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001528/ios-7-bug-or-my-bug-in-uialertview)

Comment: [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{self.table reloadData}]; Try to refresh the table view in the main thread

Comment: for reload tableView [tableView reloadData]

Comment: @tipsywacky : you are using `[self.tableView beginUpdates]`, please try to comment this line and simply use `[self.tableView reloadData]` for buttonIndex one.

Comment: try to refresh the table view in the main thread does work either. :(

Comment: Show us the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and your declaration of tableview in `.h`

Comment: Have you set your `dataSource` for tableView?

Comment: at the storyboard control click dragging to the view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Some time `reloadData` not working, so your need to `reloadData` with some delay of time such like,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    // the user clicked Yes
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(reloadTableData) withObject:self afterDelay:0.20]; // set afterDelay as per your requirement.
    }
}
```

And in method

```
-(void)reloadTableData
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

For more information

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData

Comment: He had used `reloadData`

Comment: nope, perform selector with delay doesn't work. but thanks for trying!

Comment: @tipsywacky - can you please try to change `afterDelay` as like 1 sec. ?

Comment: `withObject:self` to a method that does not take any parameter, what is with that ?

Answer (score 2):

You should just update your data source and calling `reloadData` should work.

```
 (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    // the user clicked Yes
    if (buttonIndex == 1) 
    {
        // TODO : Update your data source (most likely array) here.   

        NSLog(@"refreshing...");
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

I have two comments on your updates:

1. You are using `listItems` to populate your `cell.textLabel.text` and objectForKey `word` is used. Try to update the value of key `word` in `listItems` collection. So the new value is used by your cell event.
2. Avoid using the same name `tableView` for your UITableView, as this name is used by its events. I personally either take care to use `self` methodology or uses a different name to avoid warning of similar instance name.

Comment: From Apple Docs *The button indices start at 0* and the first button is **No** button.

Comment: Yes, I just see the OP updated the question with alertview code.

Comment: IMO it would be better to use cancelButtonIndex: if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW19), *It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates*

You have to use the `reloaddata` only, not the `beginUpdates`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    // the user clicked Yes
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying so many things at a time not work Sometimes.

If you have proper connections of delegate & datasource of tableview than just simply : `[self.tableView reloadData];`

will work.