# What's the best way to diagnose UIKit crashes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been running into a few UIKit crashes in the store version of my app. Crash lyrics provides me a partially symbolicated report, seen below. I know the problem is on a `UITableview` but I'm having trouble tracking it down.

What has everyone found useful for tracking down a UIKit crash with little identifying information?

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x615541ed

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38353626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x3087beab -[UIAlertView modalItem:shouldDismissForButtonAtIndex:] + 62
2  UIKit                          0x305f91f7 -[_UIModalItemsCoordinator _notifyDelegateModalItem:tappedButtonAtIndex:] + 94
3  UIKit                          0x305f90ff -[_UIModalItemAlertContentView tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 894
4  UIKit                          0x305007f3 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1078
5  UIKit                          0x305b2cb3 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 214
6  UIKit                          0x30461e09 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 316
7  UIKit                          0x303dab57 _afterCACommitHandler + 430
8  CoreFoundation                 0x2db7e039 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
9  CoreFoundation                 0x2db7b9c7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 286
10 CoreFoundation                 0x2db7bd13 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2dae6769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2dae654b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
13 GraphicsServices               0x32a536d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
14 UIKit                          0x30445891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
15 AppName                        0x00159b3b main (main.m:16)
```

Comment: Experience, I've seen all types of crashes so I usually know where to look if I get a crash log. That's nothing that you can put into an algorithm, though. In this particular case experience is not really necessary. Searching google for `_UIModalItemAlertContentView` leads to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001528/ios-7-bug-or-my-bug-in-uialertview So your problem is probably that your UIAlertViewDelegate gets deallocated while the alert is still on screen.

Comment: Just a guess (without knowing your code), but is the your alert view calling a delegate when it dismisses? Looks like the delegate has been released.