# Need help interpreting a crash log from QuincyKit

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, plcrashreporter, quincykit

I recently added QuincyKit (a crash log reporter that sits on top of PLCrashReporter) into an app and I received a crash log that I'm having trouble interpreting.

The crash log seems to be inconsistent - it says it was thread 0 that crashed, but the "Last Exception Backtrace" doesn't match with the thread 0 callstack.  The last exception points to a table method, but thread 0 callstack indicates an abort occurred during the Quincy manager initialization.

Moreover, the "Last Exception Backtrace" doesn't seem to make much sense taken on it's own - the "canEditRowAtIndexPath" method doesn't even include a call to "removeObjectAtIndex" at all (see below for the method).

Can anyone shed any light onto whether or not I should be paying attention to the "Last Exception Backtrace" or is that a red herring, and I should really be looking into why PLCrashReporter aborted during start up?

Many thanks

Crash log excerpt:

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x38362df0
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x29920fef <redacted> + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x37d0cc8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                       0x29833821 -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 0
3   DART                                 0x000906b3 -[DeliveryComplete tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:] + 262
4   UIKit                                0x2d0a3c25 -[UITableView _canEditRowAtIndexPath:] + 60
5   UIKit                                0x2d0a3a7f -[UITableView _setupCell:forEditing:atIndexPath:animated:updateSeparators:] + 130
6   UIKit                                0x2d0a1179 <redacted> + 2320
7   UIKit                                0x2cf82a31 +[UIView performWithoutAnimation:] + 72
8   UIKit                                0x2d0a0861 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 336
9   UIKit                                0x2d246383 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 498
10  UIKit                                0x2d24642f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 54
11  UIKit                                0x2d23b013 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2258
12  UIKit                                0x2d049657 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 186
13  UIKit                                0x2cf73023 -[UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 546
14  QuartzCore                           0x2c993d99 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 128
15  QuartzCore                           0x2c98f5cd <redacted> + 360
16  QuartzCore                           0x2c98f455 <redacted> + 16
17  QuartzCore                           0x2c98edf1 <redacted> + 224
18  QuartzCore                           0x2c98ebdf <redacted> + 434
19  UIKit                                0x2cf6b23b <redacted> + 126
20  CoreFoundation                       0x298e6fed <redacted> + 20
21  CoreFoundation                       0x298e46ab <redacted> + 278
22  CoreFoundation                       0x298e4ab3 <redacted> + 914
23  CoreFoundation                       0x29831201 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
24  CoreFoundation                       0x29831013 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
25  GraphicsServices                     0x3100d201 GSEventRunModal + 136
26  UIKit                                0x2cfd5a59 UIApplicationMain + 1440
27  DART                                 0x00015491 _mh_execute_header + 25745
28  libdyld.dylib                        0x38298aaf <redacted> + 2

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x38362df0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x382fe909 abort + 76
2   DART                                 0x00122dd7 -[PLCrashReporter enableCrashReporterAndReturnError:] + 1294
3   CoreFoundation                       0x2992131f <redacted> + 630
4   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x37d0cf13 <redacted> + 174
5   libc++abi.dylib                      0x37643de3 <redacted> + 78
6   libc++abi.dylib                      0x376438af __cxa_rethrow + 102
7   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x37d0cdd3 objc_exception_rethrow + 42
8   CoreFoundation                       0x2983129d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 632
9   CoreFoundation                       0x29831013 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
10  GraphicsServices                     0x3100d201 GSEventRunModal + 136
11  UIKit                                0x2cfd5a59 UIApplicationMain + 1440
12  DART                                 0x00015491 _mh_execute_header + 25745
13  libdyld.dylib                        0x38298aaf <redacted> + 2
```

"canEditRowAtIndexPath" method:

```
-(BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == SIGNER_TABLE_TAG_VALUE)
    {

        RouteStopData *currentStop = [CurrentRoute singleton].selectedStop;
        NSArray *signers = [currentStop signerNamesForStop];

        if (indexPath.row >= [signers count])
        {
            return NO;
        }

        if ([[signers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:DARK_DROP_SIGNER_STRING] ||
            [[signers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:PAPER_INVOICE_SIGNER_STRING] ||
            [[signers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:ADD_NEW_SIGNER_STRING]
            )
        {
            return NO;
        }

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ios7, it's maybe UIKit's fault.
Tableview  would like to call delegate method before dealloc.
So you can add this code in your Custom class:

```
- (void )dealloc{
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
   self.tableView.delegate  = nil;
}
```

See more in [iOS 7 bug or my bug in UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19001528/4975761)